# How do I add null to a List of generic type?

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am trying to do this:

```
protected List<T> list = new List<T>();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    list.Add(null);
}
```

I get a compiler error saying "cannot convert from null to T".

I have looked around but could not find an answer to this question.

Comment: What is `T` in this context?

Comment: @David I spent a while trying to figure this out, T is a reference type and once I added `where T : class` to the constraints I was able to add the null member. Avoidable question, but maybe someone else runs into this problem and can benefit from this.

Comment: `list = Enumerable.Repeat(default(T), size).ToList();` note, that if `T` is `struct` (e.g. `int`, `bool` etc.), `default(T)` will not be `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm sorry, literally a few seconds after posting this I noticed I didnt put a constraint into the class header and when including `where T : class` in the constraints, I can null the list member.

Comment: Or you can use `default(T)`

Comment: @Dennis_E that's actually a great one

Comment: @Dennis_E I would say you should post thus as an answer.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko (initial quesiton comments) correctly stated, that `default(T) ` will not equate to `null` when dealing with structs like `int`, `bool`, etc

Comment: If the goal is to specifically add null to the list, `default(T)`, in and of itself, does not guarantee so, therefore it wouldn't be a good answer to this post.